# Why Does NET Bible say the Passover lasted 8 days?

Tags: bible, passover

I'm accustomed to the idea that the *Passover*, or the *Feast of the Unleavened Bread*, lasts for *7 days*, beginning 15th and ending 21th.
But in the NET Bible at Luke 22:7W, one ca see:

> The celebration of the Feast of Unleavened Bread lasted eight days,
> beginning with the Passover meal. The celebrations were so close
> together that at times the names of both were used interchangeably.

So are they saying that the Passover and the Feast of the Unleavened Bread are actually two different celebrations, only used interchangeably?
But even so which are the 8 days then?

Comment: The answer is "YES" - the unleavened bread lasted a week and so the "Passover" lasted 8 days.

Comment: So which are the 8 days? 14th-21st? o 15th-22nd?

Comment: the evening of the 14th, 15th, 16th, 17th, 18th, 19th, 20th, 21st.  8 days.  This is inclusive reckoning.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now, answer accepted, please just also write an answer that I can accept it.

Comment: Answer supplied as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "YES" - the unleavened bread lasted a week and so the "Passover" lasted 8 days using inclusive reckoning.  See Lev 23:4-8 quoted below.

This is calculated as follows: the evening of Nisan the 14th, 15th, 16th, 17th, 18th, 19th, 20th, 21st - 8 days in total by inclusive reckoning.

> Lev 23:4-8 - These are the LORD’s appointed feasts, the sacred
> assemblies you are to proclaim at their appointed times. **5** The
> Passover to the LORD begins at twilight on the fourteenth day of the
> first month. **6** On the fifteenth day of the same month begins the
> Feast of Unleavened Bread to the LORD. For seven days you must eat
> unleavened bread. **7** On the first day you are to hold a sacred
> assembly; you are not to do any regular work. **8** For seven days you
> are to present an offering made by fire to the LORD. On the seventh
> day there shall be a sacred assembly; you must not do any regular
> work.’ ”

Comment: But doesn't "*twilight on the fourteenth*" mean at the very end of the 14th, when the 15th is about to begin?

Comment: @RayButterworth - these terms were nowhere near as precise then as now.  This can be seen when Christ was crucified - He died in the mid/late afternoon at the time of the "evening" sacrifice" of the Passover lamb.